# Apache Configuration, Cannot Connect to Localhost

Tags: macos, httpd.conf, apache2.4

I'm running into an issue with Apache 2.4.18 (on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6), and I cannot pinpoint what the cause is. I've spent 4 days trying to resolve this (including searching here), but I'm throwing in the towel and just asking.

I have little experience here. Following a few guides last weekend, I attempted to set up my system to allow me to develop a site as I work on learning HTML/Javascript/PHP. Following a few guides, I installed dnsmasq and attempted to configure httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf. Initially, localhost directed me to the "It Works" page, as did my virtual hosts home.dev and sites.dev. No matter what I did, I couldn't get any *.dev site to direct to my actual index.html file in my virtualdocumentroot.

I've tried

- Adding `home.dev` to `/etc/hosts`
- Turned on web sharing
- Checked firewall - Port 80 is open
- Changed DocumentRoot in `httpd.conf` to root used in virtual hosts file
- Tried many different `httpd-vhosts.conf` configurations.
- Checked quotes around my directory - initially using textedit they were different, changed in sublime 2.
- Run `apachectl configtest` - Syntax is ok

Now the issue has gotten worse. In working with config files trying to fix this, I've broken something, and I have no idea what. Accidentally overwrote the `httpd.conf` file in originals folder. Attempted to use `httpd.conf` file I found searching for the default, does not work. At this point, I'd be happy just to see 'It Works' again...

- Localhost, 127.0.0.1, home.dev, etc all open an 'is not available' or refused connection page.
- Running `sudo netstat -an | grep ':80'` returns nothing, so from the little I understand, it appears apache is not listening on 80, even though there's an explicit statement `listen 80` in `httpd.conf`.
- Run `apachectl configtest` - Syntax still ok
- Run `sudo apachectl restart` - appears to start
- Read somewhere, someone mentioned /var/log/apache2 could be missing and cause error, it's there. Error log doesn't have anything

Not sure if I should post my .conf here, any suggestions?

Thanks!

**Update 8/20:**

Still haven't found a solution, but feel like I'm making progress:

- `ping localhost` is successful (64 bytes from 127.0.0.1)
- `curl -v http://localhost/` returns 'connection refused' on all attempts (::1, fe80::1, 127.0.0.1, etc).

Somewhere, it appears apache is running (right??), I just don't understand where or how to figure it out.

- `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"` does not return anything listening on *:80. Also don't see any processes that sound like apache (only launchd, dnsmasq, mysqld, kdc, and Skype).
- my hosts file is set as such:

  127.0.0.1   localhost
  255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
  ::1             localhost
  fe80::1%lo0 localhost
- httpd.conf (previously Listen 80, this change didn't fix anything)

  `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`
- No errors in error log since 2 days ago when I accidentally deleted ServerName out of httpd.conf (added it back):)

Is there a netstat/lsof command I can enter and figure out what port apache is listening on? Maybe that will get me started in the right direction here.

Comment: I would try "ps auxw  | grep httpd" where httpd is the name of the binary file to see if it is really started. If not try to find out why it hasn't started, "strace" or whatever similar tool may be in MacOSX may help.

Comment: `Ps auxw | grep httpd` returns PID 4488, status U+. Seems to be running.

Comment: then run `lsof -p 4488` it should say which ports it is using. It would also be nice to know how exactly the command you use to run the server.

Comment: @ezra-s I really appreciate the help, got it running last night (see below). Libphp5.so is causing the issue, so commenting out got the server back online until I can fix that. Was just hard for me to ID initially - would have thought something like this would appear in the log for Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Update:

For anyone else who encounters this, hopefully I can save you the week I spent trying to fix this.

Checked Console to find "ReportCrashes" for httpd (even though `sudo apachectl start` appeared to work,and when running the command again I would get a `service already loaded` message.) Searching for crumbs I came across https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6602475?tstart=0.

As simple as it sounds, commenting out the load PHP module in httpd.conf `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` fixed everything. I can now access localhost. In the confusion I created for myself making changes, I assumed it was in the .conf file, but didn't have the original to revert to or see the issue. Obvious advice - make a backup before you change .conf files.

Now, of course, I can't use PHP, so if anyone has any tips there, that would be awesome. Libphp5.so exists in /libexec/apache2, but I also found Libphp7.so in /usr/local/php5/ (version issue??)

Comment: Hello, After do like you said.  It solve my trouble, and I can use php still. On my mac, There is a `/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf` file which load `php7_module` on `/usr/local/php5/libphp7.so`, can this help?